# Adding an additional GPU for LTC mining

Tags: litecoin, mining-hardware, gpu, mining-setup

I've just recently started litecoin mining on a kind of old AMD GPU.  My motherboard has space for 2 additional cards.  I'd like to drop in a new card specifically for litecoin mining, but...  I'm not sure if the two cards need to be identical.  Crossfire stuff is confusing me.  If I drop in a second card can it be top of the line and still have my old card do some work?

Answer (score 2):

The cards don't need to be identical. Your mining software should identify each GPU and allow you to control/use each one separately.